# Issue getting proper angle when redrawing lines

Tags: c#, math, drawing, angle

I have a collection of parent and children lines that I'm trying to redraw squarely.

my code was working really well till recently when two 45 degree angles started to not get translated properly. In the first case, I've debugged and found that it needs to be 135 and in the second it needs to be 180(can't be 0,due to draw direction)

How I get the angle between the two lines is

```
double theta1 = Math.Atan2(child.OriginalPoints.First().Y - child.OriginalPoints.Last().Y, child.OriginalPoints.First().X - child.OriginalPoints.Last().X);
        double theta2 = Math.Atan2(Parent.OriginalPoints.First().Y - Parent.OriginalPoints.Last().Y, Parent.OriginalPoints.First().X - Parent.OriginalPoints.Last().X);
        double diff = Math.Abs(theta1 - theta2);

        diff = (diff * 180) / Math.PI;

        double div = diff / roundTo;
        diff = roundTo * Math.Round(div, 0);

        if ((new List<double>() { 180, 360 }).Contains(Math.Abs(diff)))
        {
            diff = 0;
        }

        return diff;
```

Then to create the new points to represent my line I take the current angle to parent minus the prevAngle so that it rotates properly then use the previous lines endpoint, the length of the current line and some math to get the endpoint.

```
 double angle = line.AngleToParent - Math.Abs(prevAngle);

        double radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
        line.EndPoint.X = (line.Length * Math.Cos(radians)) + line.StartPoint.X;
        line.EndPoint.Y = (line.Length * Math.Sin(radians)) + line.StartPoint.Y;
```

This had been working until the two above angles. Where the first one is 45-180 = -135 and the next one second one is 45 - 135 == -90.

Please let me know if you can see the flaw in my logic that is preventing this from translating properly without messing up the other lines.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

After two days of team and I chasing it, we figured it out.

we changed to

```
double theta1 = Math.Atan2(child.OriginalPoints.First().Y - child.OriginalPoints.Last().Y, child.OriginalPoints.First().X - child.OriginalPoints.Last().X);
    double theta2 = Math.Atan2(Parent.OriginalPoints.First().Y - Parent.OriginalPoints.Last().Y, Parent.OriginalPoints.First().X - Parent.OriginalPoints.Last().X);
    double diff = theta1 - theta2;

    diff = (diff * 180) / Math.PI;
```

and then added

```
if (line.AngleToParent < 0)
        {
            line.AngleToParent += 360;

        }
```

Now it draws everything as expected. Even if we change the start angle. Hopefully this saves someone some time.